# Wordpress Admin Bar Not Showing on frontend of site

Tags: wordpress, themes

Please could anyone help me with this problem? The wordpress admin bar is not displaying on the front-end (public visible pages) of my website. It shows when I'm logged in at the backend i.e Dashboard though. User settings are ok (set to show admin bar when viewing the site). I have tried deactivating (then, re-activating ) installed plugins, still no show.

*Just a background note:*
I recently transferred the site to my webhost (I was developing locally and everything worked and is still working). And I have a custom folder for wordpress. I was wondering if the problem has to do with this.

Please help I have searched everywhere but seems everyone is looking to *hide* the admin panel instead.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you see the admin bar in the source code when viewing the site? (View the page source and look for a `div` with the id `wpadminbar`.)

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you also have wordpress installed in a subfolder? So your Wordpress address in settings is e.g. `yourdomain.com/wp` and the site address is `yourdomain.com`?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Check that your theme includes a call to the function `wp_footer()` at some point, usually at the very bottom of footer.php.  That generates the code required for the admin bar to show.

Comment: +1 working around 2 hrs to sort out the problem, u have made it :) thanks

Comment: Interestingly this also resolved an issue where my mobile menu toggle was failing to show the mobile menu.  I had custom coded footer.php without knowing wp_footer() needed to be left in.  Thanks very much- you made my Friday!

Answer (score 23):

add this to the end of your `footer.php` in your theme folder:

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

problem solved :-)

Answer (score 10):

Most of the time the wp_footer() call is right where it should be so if you still can't see the admin bar then try the following:

1. log out of the backend
2. navigate to the front-end
3. clear your browser cache
4. log back in using the absolute url i.e. yourwebsite.co.uk/wp-admin

   and then see if it comes up - worked for me.

Also make sure the "Show Toolbar when viewing site" box is checked in your user profile page or whatever you try ain't gonna work my friend!.

Comment: One hour of bashing into plugins, themes and multisite settings, then it turns out that it's bloody browser cache... Thank you for saving me two more hours for finding this out by myself!

Comment: It wasn't the browser cache for me, but logging out and logging back in (after moving the frontend from the subfolder to the root via config and index+htaccess copying) fixed it for me, thanks a bunch AdamJB :)

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but another option - If you purchased (use) a pre-made theme make sure that theme does not remove the toolbar in its code.

Comment: Yes.  html5blank is an example of a starter theme that takes away the admin bar through use of `function remove_admin_bar()` in functions.php

Comment: Thank you. This case is very common and solved my problem. Those who are checking for `wp_footer` should also check this function (or similar) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Does it 'know' that you are logged in ? when in front end ? ie: meta widget shows 'logout' instead of login.  if not Did you by any chance play around  with the cookie paths?

I got myself confused because I was logged in at backend, but not front end.  This was because  I'd being playing with the cookie path and forgot to uncomment what I'd done.

Comment: Disabled all plugins, activated original Twenty Fourteen theme, ruled out CSS rules because the element simply wasn't on the page... Saw this answer, logged out, logged in, and voila. I had deleted a cookie manually and it left me logged in to the back-end and not the front somehow. Thank you!

Comment: I wish I could upvote again... I didn't delete any cookies this time but somehow this same thing happened again. Thankfully my google breadcrumb trail led me straight back here.

Answer (score 2):

First, double checked all of the other items mentioned here (`wp_footer()`, etc).

Three more things to check:

- make sure header.php has `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` not just `<body>`
- try disabling plugins one by one if you're still having trouble. (For me, the Simplest Gallery 2.7 with WP 3.7.1 caused a conflict that made the admin bar disappear)
- look for `function remove_admin_bar() { return false; }` in the theme's functions.php - change it to `return true`.

Comment: This did the trick for me, and I just want to say it's the absolute definition of counter-intuitive. 'Remove admin bar' = False? This removes the admin bar. If you want to NOT remove the admin bar, set 'Remove admin bar' to true. There's twenty minutes of my life I won't get back...

Answer (score 1):

Just add in your template 
`<?php wp_footer(); ?>` before `</body>` and `<?php wp_head(); ?>` before `</head>`

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that I was using http://mydomain.com/wp in the WordPress address but http://www.mydomain.com for the site address. We had added the www to the WordPress address so that GoogleAnalytics would work and that's when the Admin Bar broke.

Adding www to the WordPress address fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify after a lot of searching for a solution, similar to MattKnowles solution but more specific: Make sure that in settings > WordPress Address (URL) and settings > Site address (URL) that if one has www then the other also does and the other way round. Otherwise it seems while you are browsing the site it is a different domain to the admin area and the admin bar does not show.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure site addresses are the same! I had one set at http://www.example.com and the other (WordPress) address set to http://example.com or visa versa.

I had them set this way because I though it was needed for the site to show up when you type the url without the www.

Now that both addresses are the same (with the www) my admin bar works, I stay logged in, I can comment, see preview or draft content, cross-site authenticate and logout, wow!

an entire year of wondering why WP just never worked right across over 30 websites!

Going to change addresses to the same "www" address in the rest of my 30 sites now and enjoy error-free WordPress for the first time ever...it's a great day!

Remember to remove any admin bar code you may have added in your theme's function.php file or in your styles.CSS

Thanks to all who help us here!

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_footer() ,
```

add this function to `footer.php`

Answer (score 0):

My #wpadminbar had a z-index: 99999;

In an act of myopia I made a sticky header that was in conflict with the Admin bar's stickiness. I had a z-index greater than the admin, making it rest behind the visible div.

I made my own sticky less powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that I found. 
Need to have `<? wp_head()?>` and `<? wp_footer(); ?>`.

More info: http://blog.frontendfactory.com/how-to-add-wordpress-toolbar-to-your-custom-theme/

Answer (score 0):

Still working on this, but there is a conflict with Woocommerce. if deactivated, toolbar is there. Active, no toolbar. 
More info [here](https://www.role-editor.com/woocommerce-admin-bar-access).

Answer (score 0):

I had a sitiation when the admin dashboard was opened in one Chrome tab, but I could not make front-end part opened in the other tab to enter the admin state and show the admin bar.

The front-end always opened as if I had not logged in as an admin in the other tab.

The issue was that I had the site opened in yet another Chrome window (not tab) as not-logged-in visitor.

As soon as I closed all the tabs and all the sessions and reopened the single Chrome window with two tabs (admin / front end) the admin bar appeared in the front end.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of **unclosed HTML tags** above `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`. Unclosed tags in the source will have closing tags generated by the browser and can suck in the WordPress admin bar HTML.

```
...
    <div class="hidden-by-css">
      <span> You can't see this</span>

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

That will cause the HTML generated for the admin bar to get sucked into the `.hidden-by-css` DIV and your admin bar won't show up.

So make sure you close all your tags. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanna leave my solution since I tried literally every possible solution on the internet. The website has LiteSpeed and is behind a reverse proxy from Deflect.ca similar to cloudflare, it blocks and caches as well.

The problem is the default cache from Deflect is set on 10 minutes and that caused the problem. Setting it with lower settings and removing all admin caching from LiteCache solved everything.