# Admin bar not displayed on some posts and pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My Wordpress admin bar doesn't appear on my home page and a few random posts. I've looked at many topics on the web about it, including this [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214647/wordpress-admin-bar-not-showing-on-frontend-of-site), and I've tried all solutions :

- I use a commercial theme that has wp_footer() and wp_head()
- Wordpress and site URL are the same, with https://www
- I have checked the box in my user profile
- I've disabled all my plug-ins : the problem still occurs

The difference with all the other occurrences of this issue I came across browsing the web is that it only occurs on some pages and posts.

Comment: Any errors show up in your error_log?

Comment: Messages like this (in French sorry) :
`Notice: get_currentuserinfo est <strong>obsolète</strong> depuis la version 4.5.0 ! Utilisez wp_get_current_user() à la place. in /home/revuebalvp/www/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3853`
`Deprecated: Function create_function() is deprecated in /home/revuebalvp/www/wp-content/plugins/footnotes/class/init.php on line 61`

Comment: And on my host error log, a lot of CGI errors such as :
`FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server` & 
`FastCGI: An error happend on Fastcgi processing, fallback to CGI,`

Comment: Do those errors occur when any page/post is accessed, or only when pages that aren't properly displaying the admin bar are accessed?

Comment: I think the ones on the WP debug log happen on every post, they are caused by old plugins. I disabled the one using `get_currentuserinfo`. The FastCGI ones happened before I had this admin bar issue.

Comment: Do the pages and posts that have the issue all use the same page and post templates as the ones that work? Or are they different?

Comment: Same template for the posts, and same template for the home page and category pages (blog list), and same template for single pages. So the issue happens and doesn't happen on posts/pages that have the same template.

Comment: And it seems the posts & pages with the issue won't update, as if they were cached, even if I disabled my cache plugin and manually removed all files in wp-content/cache...

Comment: Did you also clear your browser cache?  What versions of WP and PHP are you using?

Comment: Yes I did, and logged out, removed all data (including cookies), logged in, several times ! I'm using PHP 7.2 (but the issue started under 7.1) and Wordpress 4.9.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not in my Wordpress installation but due to bad cache management from my host CDN (OVH, FYI). So I disabled the CDN, and I'm back to normal...